# Scheduling unit on linux

Tags: linux-kernel

I hear linux kernel see thread as kernel thread and process as group of thread which using same virtual memory space.

I know that on Window, scheduling unit is thread.

Is that mean window and linux kernel's scheduling unit is thread??

what is the minumum scheduling unit of linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, the scheduling unit on Linux is referred to as a KSE, a "kernel scheduling entity". On modern Linux systems, each thread is a KSE.